# (Inductive Proofs) Show why one inductive hypothesis works, and the other does not.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Here's a homework problem I have for my class about Discrete Mathematics:

> Suppose that we want to prove that
>
> $$\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2n-1}{2n} < \frac1{\sqrt{3n}}$$
>
> for all positive integers $n$.
>
> a) Show that if we try to prove this inequality using mathematical
>   induction, the basis step works but the inductive step fails.
>
> b) Show that mathematical induction can be used to prove the stronger
>   inequality
>
> $$\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2n-1}{2n} < \frac1{\sqrt{3n + 1}}$$
>
> for all integers greater than $1$, which, together with a verification
>   for the case where $n = 1$, establishes the weaker inequality we
>   originally tried to prove using mathematical induction.

I'm not sure how to proceed in the inductive step. I have

$$\begin{align*}P(k)&: \frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2k-1}{2k} < \frac1{\sqrt{3k}}\\
P(k+1)&:\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2(k+1)-1}{2(k+1)} < \frac1{\sqrt{3(k+1)}}
\end{align*}$$

then from that point (which is the very beginning) I'm stumped. This answer exists on [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090225141825AAgvdZC), but there's no explanation to the technique. Neither my friends nor my professor have given me a clear step by step answer to the problem. If someone could, it'd be very much appreciated!

Comment: Related (and possibly dupe): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119773/how-does-one-prove-that-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdots-frac2n-12n-leq

Comment: What the not well-worded (a) presumably means is that given an (unknown) $f(k)$ such that $f(k)<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3k}}$, we cannot deduce that $f(k)\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+1}}$.  It is an interesting fact that sometimes to prove a result by induction, the natural approach is to prove a stronger result. A simpler example would be proving that $\sum_1^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)}<1$. Using **only** $\sum_1^k \frac{1}{i(i+1)}<1$, nothing else, we cannot show that  $\sum_1^{k+1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)}<1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For (a), the first thing to do is show that the basis step works, i.e., that $P(1)$ is true. $P(1)$ says that $\frac12<\frac1{\sqrt3}$; since $2>\sqrt3$, this is true. The second part of (a) is to show that you can’t make the induction step work; that is, you can’t assume $P(k)$ and deduce $P(k+1)$. The natural way to try to start the induction step is this:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2(k+1)-1}{2(k+1)}&=\left(\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)\cdot\frac{2(k+1)-1}{2(k+1)}\\
&<\frac1{\sqrt{3k}}\cdot\frac{2(k+1)-1}{2(k+1)}\;,
\end{align*}$$

because the induction hypothesis $P(k)$ says that the product in the large parentheses is less than $\frac1{\sqrt{3k}}$.

Then you’d want to show that $$\frac1{\sqrt{3k}}\cdot\frac{2(k+1)-1}{2(k+1)}\le\frac1{\sqrt{3(k+1)}}\;,\tag{1}$$ from which $P(k+1)$ would follow immediately. $(1)$ can be simplified to $$\frac{2k+1}{2(k+1)\sqrt{3k}}\le\frac1{\sqrt{3k+3}}\;.\tag{2}$$ Unfortunately, when we substitute $k=1$ into this, we get $$\frac3{4\sqrt3}\le\frac1{\sqrt6}\;,$$ which is equivalent to $3\sqrt6\le4\sqrt3$, which implies (by squaring) that $9\cdot 6\le 16\cdot 3$, or $54\le 48$. Since this is obviously false, the natural approach to the induction step simply cannot work.

In fact the same idea can be applied to $(2)$ without substituting a value for $k$: it’s equivalent to $(2k+1)\sqrt{3k+k}\le2(k+1)\sqrt{3k}$, which implies that $3(2k+1)^2(k+1)\le12k(k+1)^2$ and hence that $(2k+1)^2\le4k(k+1)$, i.e., that $4k^2+4k+1\le4k^2+4k$, which is clearly false.

I’ll leave you to try (b) on your own for now. For the induction step try to follow the pattern that **didn’t** work above.

Comment: I don't understand how the inductive step in a) may fail. 
For such thing to happen, the hypothesis would have to be false, but we know (e.g. by second part) it _is_ true (or maybe we speak about different hypotheses?). Wrong proof is not a proof of impossibility.

Comment: @dtldarek: Agreed. I think that the problem is very badly worded and have simply answered the question that was clearly intended.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yeah, the topic was called "Strengthening the Inductive Hypothesis," not to be confused with Strong Induction. Is it important in eq. (1) that the sign is <= rather than simply <? In part b) I completed all steps an found P(k+1) to be true but I don't really know why I used <= in the proof.

Comment: @Maharlikans: I want to show that $\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{2(k+1)-1}{2(k+1)}<\frac1{\sqrt{3k+1}}$. I’ve already shown that it’s $<\frac1{\sqrt{3k}}\cdot\frac{2(k+1)-1}{2(k+1)}$, so showing that $\frac1{\sqrt{3k}}\cdot\frac{2(k+1)-1}{2(k+1)}<\frac1{\sqrt{3k+1}}$ would be overkill; it’s enough to show $\le$, as I wrote at $(1)$. Getting rid of the clutter: if I want $a<c$, and I’ve shown that $a<b$, it’s good enough to show that $b\le c$; I don’t need to show that $b<c$.

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks a ton.